# How to get the textarea of ShareJS to autofocus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, sharejs

Typically it is possible to get a textarea to focus using the `autofocus` attribute or with jQuery such as `$('textarea').focus();`

Using the textarea provided by the [ShareJS](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs) package for Meteor breaks these assumptions.

There is a [demo](http://documents.meteor.com/) of ShareJS for meteor.

Comment: yes this will work $('textarea').focus();

Comment: Usually it does. Unfortunately it doesn't work with this particular package.